# How to use NVL to get data from GemFire when query result is null

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, spring-repositories, oql

I am using *Spring Data GemFire* in a project and I am using a Repository to fetch  query results from a cache as mentioned here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-gemfire/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/gemfire-repositories.html

Below is my *Repository* interface:

```
@Repository
@Region("someRegion")
public interface SomeRegionRepository  extends GemfireRepository<CustomObject, Object> {

    //Below works when id exists in gemfire region. 
    //But when id does not exists it
    //gives java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported query
    @Query("select a.num from /someRegion a where a.id = $1")
    Integer getNumById(String id);

    //Below returns CustomObject instance when id exists in gemfire region. 
    //But when id does not exists it returns null (Expected)
    CustomObject findById(String id);

}
```

Is there any way I can return 0 or some other value when there is no data found for that key in OQL query?

Or, is there any way I can get a `null` value so that I can handle it in the caller code when there is no data?

There is something called `NVL` (which allows returning other value/expressions in case first expression evaluates to null) in OQL specified here: https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/developing/query_select/the_select_statement.html . But I am not able to get the right syntax of how to use it.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one house keeping item before we begin...

I see that you referenced *Pivotal GemFire* `9.7` in your GemFire documentation reference above, but then reference Spring *Data GemFire* (SDG) `1.3.3.RELEASE` reference docs.  I certainly hope you are not trying to use SDG `1.3.3.RELEASE` with Pivotal GemFire `9.7`.  SDG 1.3.3 is quite date, based on Pivotal GemFire 7.0.1, and is no longer supported.

I suspect you are not using SDG `1.3.x`, therefore you should probably always reference the latest documentation, available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/), and specifically, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories).  Even a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Spring%20Data%20GemFire%20Reference%20Guide&oq=Spring%20Data%20GemFire%20Reference%20Guide&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2.8543j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals the latest docs.

Also, you can refer to the *Spring Data for Pivotal GemFire* [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix) for more details.  Anyway...

So, I wrote a [test class](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java) to better understand your UC.

In my test, I modeled a [Person class](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L185-L201) with a queryable [`age` field/property](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L192).  I have a [PersonRepository](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L203-L208) for the `Person` type, and I wrote a very similar query to your example above, to query a person by age, in an [usual](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L77-L78) as well as [null-safe](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L74-L75) manner.

The thing is, your desire to want to protect against the absence of results by returning `null` or `0` is ambiguous in the case of *Repositories*.

For 1, if you had returned multiple results (e.g. as in `SELECT a.num FROM /SomeRegion a`; i.e. without a predicate), and the results were not ordered, then you would have no way to know which value was `null` for which key unless you also returned the key in the result set.

Of course, that is not the case here and you did qualify the query by ID using a predicate (i.e. `... WHERE a.id = $1`).  However, in this case, it is not clear when looking at the query (i.e. `SELECT a.num FROM ...`), whether there was no result for the given ID (i.e. Key) or that simply **num** was `null`.  You really don't know.

My test goes on to illustrate this point.

I have 2 people `["Jon Doe", "Jane Doe"]`, [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L94-L95).  Jon has a declared age and Jane does not.  Of course, both people exist in the cache (i.e. "People" Region).

When I query for Jon and assert his age, I get the [expected result](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L103).

Alternatively, when I query for Jane and assert her age, I can get 1 of two values, either `null` or `0`, as [expected here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L108) (currently `0` because I am using the [null-safe query](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L80)).  If I change the query to the [usual query](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L77-L78), then the return value for Jane's `age` would in fact be `null`, and I could assert as such.

However, when we get down to querying for a non-existing person, the behavior of GemFire is clear; there are no results.  I illustrated this 2 different ways (other than using a Repository), using GemFire's [`QueryService` API](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L123-L137) directly, and then again using SDG's convenient [`GemfireTemplate` class](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L143-L151), which simply wraps the GemFire Query API (it is also the method used by the *Repository* under the hood; really, the value Repositories add is the mapping/conversion capabilities).

As you can see, I must handle the presence of no results, for [example](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L136).

In the the case of the Repository, because you have used a custom query, it is not immediately apparent to the Repository infrastructure, which part (i.e. intermediate result of the query) was `null`.

What if you had `SELECT person.address.city.name FROM ...`?

Is person `null`, address `null` or city `null`?  How should this be handled consistently?  The person might exit but the address might be `null`, which might warrant different behavior than if either person or city were `null`.

In fact, the *Repository* abstraction does handle `null` return values, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L113).

So, where do we go from here?

We have several options:

1. You could perform and [existence check](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#existsById-ID-), first...

   return personRepository.existsById(bobDoe.getName()) 
       ? personRepository.getAge(bobDoe.getName())
       : 0;
2. You could handle this outside of a *Repository* in a DAO (perhaps adapting/decorating the *Repository* and delegating for simple query cases, rather than complex queries that involve using the `@Query` annotation, which should be used sparingly).

   @Repository
   class PersonDao {

   ```
   @Autowired
   private PersonRepository personRepository;

   Person findById(String name) {
       return this.personRepository.findById(name).orElse(null);
   }

   Integer getAge(String name) {
       // Either use the approach in #1, or do https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/NullValueReturningRepositoryQueryMethodIntegrationTests.java#L143-L151.
   }

   ...
   ```

   }

   Still
3. Another option would be for us to provide additional support in SD, something along the lines of...

   `@Nullable Integer getAge(String name);`

   Or perhaps...

   `Optional<Integer> getAge(String name);`

   Still this approach does not solve the ambiguity problem and will require more thought.
4. What would be really nice is if OQL handle a Elvis operator, something like (in my more complex example above)...

   SELECT person?.address?.city?.name FROM /People ...

Anyway, I hope this gives you some ideas.  I will need to think on #3 above more before moving forward.

If you have additional questions/feedback/ideas, please provide them in the comments or feel free to file a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF).

Thanks!